# Trying Repo Github repository, but error showing Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

https://github.com/Akshitaag/ACM-WH
I repo this in vs code and tried running it as shown
The project started on server but showing error while trying to use register
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/rajivjain/Desktop/ACM-WH/C:/Users/hp/ACM-WH/public/register.html'

Help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. If you check the "routes" directory, then take a look at where the register route is taking you, its file path is linked as this:

```
router.get("/register",function(req,res){
    //res.sendFile("/home/rahmeen/Desktop/ACM-WH/public/register.html");
    res.sendFile("C:/Users/hp/ACM-WH/public/register.html");
});
```

The issue with this is that it's linking to the route the file is in starting with the developer's C drive.

It seems like the developers have not yet discovered the proper usage of the path module, which is a module baked into Node; however, they are using it within the server.js.

Try replacing that entire route code referenced above with this:

```
const path = require('path');

router.get("/register",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/register.html'));
});
```

I'd also recommend cleaning up the file structure of this repo.

Comment: thanks the code worked

Comment: mark the answer with a check to show everyone!